# How to use cross-validation with custom estimator in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written a custom estimator class with a `fit` and `transform` method. I am able to create a model, train and predict using the model.

However, while doing cross-validation, I run into this error: `TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object`.

This is how `CustomEstimator` looks like:

```
class DefaultEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, preprocessor, pipelines):
      self.preprocessor = preprocessor
      self.pipelines = pipelines

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
      for each_pipeline in self.pipelines:
          each_pipeline.fit(self.preprocessor.apply(X), y)
      return self

   def transform(self, X):
     transformed_data = []
     for each_pipeline in self.pipelines:
        transformed_data.append(each_pipeline.transform(self.preprocessor.apply(X)))
     return sp.hstack(transformed_data)
```

Does anyone have an idea on approaching this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code? Inheriting from `BaseEstimator` works perfectly (see https://github.com/luispedro/BuildingMachineLearningSystemsWithPython/blob/third_edition/ch11/chapter_11.ipynb for an example).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Added the code for `CustomEstimator`

Comment: It may be that the pipelines and the preprocessor cannot be deepcopies? Can you check that?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes that's the issue. Preprocessor cannot be deepcopies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in few comments, this error is because `self.processor` can't be deep-cloned.

So, the workaround for this error is to remove preprocessing step from this class and move it as independent preprocessing step or inside the pipeline itself.

Comment: Do you know how to workaround this error when it is mandatory to transform data? In my case, i need to use `LabelBinarizer` to classify/predict

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the preprocessor inside the pipeline itself. `Cross_val_score` would try to copy the params of the estimator, it would break when the estimator cannot return the params while calling `get_params()`.

I am not sure whether your pipeline parameter is a Sklearn pipeline because the pipeline object is not iterable.

Comment: True, I checked. This is the issue I am encountering, with preprocessor. However, I am constructing preprocessor based on a boolean configuration file. So everytime during training, a preprocessor class object is created which is used for preprocessing.

On a different note, `pipeline` parameter is a Sklearn pipeline and it's working perfectly without adding preprocessor.