# Custom estimator can't be deepcopied by cross_val_score

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I have a custom estimator that i implemented myself and i am not able to use `cross_val_score()`, which i believe it has something to do with my `predict()` method. Here is the full error trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joann/Desktop/Implementações ML/Adaboost Classifier/test.py", line 30, in <module>
    ada2_score = cross_val_score(ada_2, X, y, cv=5)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 390, in cross_val_score
    error_score=error_score)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 236, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1004, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 835, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 754, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 209, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 590, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 256, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 544, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 591, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 89, in __call__
    score = scorer(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 371, in _passthrough_scorer
    return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joann/Desktop/Implementações ML/Adaboost Classifier/Adaboost.py", line 92, in score
    scr_pred = self.predict(X)
  File "/Users/joann/Desktop/Implementações ML/Adaboost Classifier/Adaboost.py", line 73, in predict
    clf_pred = clf.predict(X)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn_extensions/extreme_learning_machines/elm.py", line 614, in predict
    class_predictions = self.binarizer.inverse_transform(raw_predictions)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 528, in inverse_transform
    self.classes_, threshold)
  File "/Users/joann/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 750, in _inverse_binarize_thresholding
    format(y.shape))
ValueError: output_type='binary', but y.shape = (30, 3)
```

My `predict(self, X)` method returns a vector of size `n_samples` with the predictions for the `X` parameter. I also made a `score()` function as follows:

```
def score(self, X, y):
    scr_pred = self.predict(X)
    return sum(scr_pred == y) / X.shape[0]
```

This method simply computes the accuracy of the model given the samples. Either if i use this `score()` method or set a `cross_val_score(... , scoring="accuracy")` it is not working.

**Note**: i am aware of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636101/using-custom-estimator-with-cross-val-score-fails) but this doesn't apply to my case because i can confirm the consistence of my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, estimators=["MLP"], n_rounds=5, random_state=10):
    self.estimators = estimators
    self.n_rounds = n_rounds
    self.random_state = random_state
```

**UPDATE**:

Further research led me to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233126/how-to-use-cross-validation-with-custom-estimator-in-sklearn), where it is explained that `sklearn` can't deepcopy Estimators with transformers. However, it is mandatory for my estimator to run `LabelBinarizer` to transform data to get the predictions. So i update the question title to the proper issue.`

Comment: The problem here is with the shape of y. It seems somewhere in code you would have done some kind of label encoding or something else. Check on if fit_transform and transform is done or not for the test data.

Comment: You mean the shape of y returned by predict method? Theres no transformation being done with the data.

Comment: I think we'd need more of your code at least, preferably a MRE.  It might be a problem in `sklearn_extensions.extreme_learning_machines`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However the problem statement of yours is not clear here but however looking at the error it seems you are trying a multiclass classification.

The problem here is that you might have in your code at some point have not done the preprocessing correctly as the error is logged from inverse_binarize_thresholding which is raised due to below functionality of sklearn pre-prosessing:

```
def _inverse_binarize_thresholding(y, output_type, classes, threshold):
   
    if output_type == "binary" and y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] > 2:
        raise ValueError("output_type='binary', but y.shape = {0}".
                         format(y.shape))
```

There must be some missing transformation or pre-prosessing in your code and you have to use LabelBinarizer correctly

Go through the below documentation and backtrack the error to fix your code

[documentation](https://ibex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn/preprocessing/label.html)